# What is the difference between these two sentences ("I was told" vs "I had been told")?

Tags: past-tense, passive-voice

What is the difference between these two sentences:

> I went to see it because *I had been told* it was a good film by all my friends.

and

> I went to see it because *I was told* it was a good film by all my friends.

Comment: A minor correction: it should be *these* two sentences, because it's plural.  "This" would refer to only one thing.  Also, please try to use titles that would be useful to other learners.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way you are using your sentences they mean the same.

However, the past perfect

> had been told

usually signifies something that has happened (and completed) in the more distant past than the simple past

> was told

So

> Originally, I *had been told* the house was brown, but then I *was told* it is actually yellow.

means you were first told the house was brown, and then later told it was yellow.